# How to open specific browser, if installed

Tags: c++, windows, google-chrome, firefox, browser

I am currently opening webpages in the system's default browser using

```
std::string url = "http://stackoverflow.com";
ShellExecute(0, 0, url.c_str(), 0, 0, SW_SHOW);
```

As I have several users with an old Internet Explorer as default, I want to automatically open the page with either Firefox or Chrome **if installed** (otherwise or if one of them is already the default, the system's default browser should be used).

```
char buffer[MAX_PATH];
HINSTANCE handle = FindExecutable(url.c_str(), NULL, buffer);
```

only returns the [one associated executable](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb776419(v=vs.85).aspx) and not the list of possible programs like displayed in the "Open with" context menu:
[image: file context menu: Open with]

Is there another way than trying hard-coded installation paths?

Comment: Check the installed software repository via WMI (use the method to retrieve the packages available for uninstalling to avoid the consistency check applied when querying the installed software packages).

Comment: Look in the Registry for installed browsers, such as in keys like `HKLM\SOFTWARE\Clients\StartMenuInternet`, `(HKLM|HKCU)\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\App Paths`, `HKCR\Applications`, etc